# loop through elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i've never looped through elements with jquery and it would be great with some help.

my DOM looks like:

```
<div class="section">

    <div class="group">
        <div class="comment">
            <input class="comment" type="text" />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <input class="link" type="text" />
            <input class="link" type="text" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <div class="comment">
            <input class="comment" type="text" />
            <input class="comment" type="text" />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <input class="link" type="text" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

how do i write the code to get all values in text input fields (class=comment and class=link). there will be lot of groups with different numbers of text input fields.

thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$(":input.comment, :input.link").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val()); // or this.val
});
```

See:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each
- http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/input

Comment: val is a function, so you need parens.  ()

Comment: Thanks Kyle, it was a speed related omission. Just fixed it,

Comment: `:input` matches any kind of input element, including select, so I figured it would be useful to include it. Of course, text inputs can be selected as `input[type=text]`, but thanks for the comment

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that.  I deleted my comment when you posted the second doc link.  Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 5):

This selects all elements with a class of comment or link, and alerts its value.

```
$(".comment, .link").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Alternatively, you could select on the input type:

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but you need to lose the space between `input` and the `[type=text]` attribute filter, `input[type=text]`.

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax is clearer to me (although it's functionally equivalent to the other answers):

```
var elementList = $(":input.comment, :input.link");
$.each(elementList, function(i, input){
    alert($(input).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the question.

First line for onload:  We need to loop through using each loop.
Second Line for looping the text fields, suppose you need loop a different input type - just replace with that
Third line - Ensuring it is not blank
Fourth line - will be your business logic (In this case, im trying to parse the input text field.)

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5FVtR/86/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(":text").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() !='') {
            $(this).val()=parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2)
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(":input.comment, :input.link", "div.group").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```